# Moving from git to subversion (yes, that way round): Using the trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, git-svn

I have been using git for 2 years now and love it.  However, I am doing some work for a company that insist in using svn so I need to port my git way of doing things to svn.

This is what I have learned so far:

```
svn co https://the.remote.repo
touch myrepo/trunk/mytest.c
svn add myrepo/trunk/mytest.c 
cd myrepo/
svn commit -m "added test file"
```

which checks out my repo, adds a file, commit it and then pushes it.

I already have a non-svn project (non-git too, it's not under version control yet (awful I know)).  How can I turn my existing project into a svn repo ?  I can do this:

```
svn co https://the.remote.repo my_existing_non_svn_directory
```

which creates a `trunk` sub-directory in `my_existing_non_svn_directory`.  With `git` there is no `trunk` so this would work but with `svn`, do I have to move all my code into the trunk ?  Is there some way round this or is it just an `svn` thing ?

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no need to stop using git.  Use `git-svn` instead.  You can keep a local git repository, and `git-svn` will push your changes into svn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Subversion (unlike Git), you can easily check out a partial tree. So in your first example you might do:

```
svn co https://the.remote.repo/trunk myrepo
```

Then you won't have the trunk/tags/branches hierarchy in your working directory, which makes this simpler and faster.

In your second example, if you have a mostly empty Subversion repo (where you have set up the trunk/tags/branches hierarchy), then you can check out `https://the.remote/repo/trunk` and get an empty directory into which you can add your files.

Answer (score 1):

You can import unversioned tree into repository:

```
>svn help import
import: Commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository.

svn import my_existing_non_svn_directory https://the.remote.repo/trunk
```

and work over git-svn with this repo later

Another style

- `svn co` empty new trunk
- copy project-tree into WC
- add/ignore/commit